# How do I make Ansible ignore failed tarball extraction?

Tags: ansible

I have a command in an ansible playbook:

```
- name: extract the tarball
  command: tar --ignore-command-error -xvkf release.tar
```

It is expected that some files won't be extracted as they exist already (`-k` flag).

However, this results in ansible stopping the overall playbook as there is an error code from the tar extraction.

How can I work around this? As you can see I have tried `--ignore-command-error` to no avail.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You want to use the `ignore_errors` argument:

```
- name: extract the tarball
  command: tar --ignore-command-error -xvkf release.tar
  ignore_errors: yes
```

See ["Ignore Failed Commands" in the Error Handling documentation page](http://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_error_handling.html#ignoring-failed-commands).

`ignore_errors` works best when you can detect success in some manner- you can `register` the output and check that, or you can use `creates` to look for a specific filename.

Comment: @tedder42, can we give `ignore_errors` on a playbook level instead of a task level?

Comment: @codebender I wish! I think some of the exception handling in 2.0 will help in those cases.

Answer (score 10):

`ignore_errors: yes` will still raise an error showing the failed task on the prompt. If you want that task to fail silently, you can set `failed_when: false` or more sophisticated condition like described in the [manual](http://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_error_handling.html#ignoring-failed-commands):

```
- name: this command prints FAILED when it fails
  command: /usr/bin/example-command -x -y -z
  register: command_result
  failed_when: "'FAILED' in command_result.stderr"
```

So you could search the output of `stderr`. You maybe still want to fail if the file is not readable, not exists or whatever, but not fail when the archive is broken and can't be extracted.